# `vagrant box list` returning "Malformed version number string virtualbox (ArgumentError)"

Tags: vagrant

After upgrading vagrant version, when I run `vagrant box list` I get a `Malformed version number string virtualbox (ArgumentError)` error:

```
$ vagrant box list
my_box             (virtualbox, 0)
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb:191:in `initialize': Malformed version number string virtualbox (ArgumentError)
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:277:in `new'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:277:in `block (2 levels) in find'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:272:in `map'
...
```

What's broken vagrant? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that somewhere along the line virtualbox changed the way they store box versions. They used to be stored by name; now they're stored by number.

```
$ tree -L 2 .vagrant.d/boxes/
.vagrant.d/boxes/
└── my_box
    └── 0           # <-- new format, keep this
    └── virtualbox  # <-- old, offending format
```

In the above case, the `virtualbox` directory is the problem - to get `vagrant box list` working again, delete the offending version like so:

```
rm -rf .vagrant.d/boxes/my_box/virtualbox
```